# How to add domain filter in odoo search view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to add a custom search filter like this :

[image]

[image]

when I apply a filter like this is doesn't work

```
<filter string="Societe" name="company_id" domain='[("company_id","like","")]'/>
```

in my case, I want the condition is what the user enters on the search input input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you just need to add the field `company_id` as extension to a search view or just add it in your own search view:

```xml
<field name="company_id" />
```

And that's it. Now while typing a search term, the search view should show the user multiple search options.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you shoud apply it on the name field.

```xml
 domain='[("company_id.name","like","")]'
```